# CSS not updating properly

Tags: html, css, drupal

I'm currently developing a website in Drupal and I'm trying to put a custom twitter block. Here's my HTML code:

```
<ul id="twitter_update_list" class="twitter"><li>Twitter feed loading</li></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/terryamorin.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=5"></script>
```

And here is the relevant custom CSS:

```css
#twitter_update_list a {
color: #CA0A6C;
}
```

Now for some reason the code won't update properly or will only work for one link and not all of them. I checked with firebug and if I choose the element and disable/re-enable the font-size in here:

```css
element.style {
    font-size: 85%;
}
```

then it shows properly for that one link. Why is this happening? Am I not overriding the right properties?

UPDATED:

```
<div class="content">
<ul id="twitter_update_list" class="twitter">
<li><span>Vote for Cooper in the Fido Casting Call once a day every day! We could have our own UOGC puppy in a commercial !! <a href="http://t.co/bDwdKlQ6">http://t.co/bDwdKlQ6</a></span> <a style="font-size:85%" href="http://twitter.com/UOGreekCouncil/statuses/237535525911793664">about 15 hours ago</a></li></ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/javascripts/blogger.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/uogreekcouncil.json?callback=twitterCallback2&amp;count=1"></script></div>
```

FIXED:

I used the following CSS instead and it seemed to work:

```
#twitter_update_list a{
    color: #CA0A6C;
    }
```

Comment: Could you provide the HTML that the JavaScript *produces*? None of those selectors will match anything in the HTML you've provided to us.

Comment: I've added the HTML code you asked for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply a case of your attribute selector not actually matching. The attribute getting set on the actual element is `style="font-size:85%"`, while the attribute you're searching for in your CSS is `style="font-size: 85%;"` (notice the extra space and the addition of a semicolon). **The text must match perfectly.**

You *could* change the selector to look for the actual style property being set:

```css
#twitter_update_list a[style="font-size:85%"]
```

[See the jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/46MEb/2/)

Additionally, since those links appear to be the only ones using inline styles, you could just look for the presence of the style attribute, like so:

```css
#twitter_update_list a[style]
```

Since you're using an external JavaScript file to create this HTML, modifying it to use classes instead probably isn't an option, although that's what I'd ultimately recommend. Looking for specific styles may work for now, but if the JavaScript ever changes and the structure isn't exactly the same, it will instantly break your CSS.

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work so I backtracked a little. I've reduced my css to 1 line and updated my HTML for one tweet instead of 4 (please see original post for changes). In that one tweet, I have  links; one of which is the colour I want, and the other isn't. Now sometimes they alternate but they don't both change. Any ideas?

Comment: I just checked with Firebug again and this time the problem seems to be that another style is "Master". There's a style for all links in the footer. If I disable that, my colour shows properly. Is there a way to override that style?

Comment: @Simon: What is the selector for it? Perhaps your current one could be tweaked to overwrite that one.

Comment: I just changed from #twitter_update_list a to #twitter_update_list li a:link and that seemed to fix my problem. In firebug it's showing the proper order for my styles. Is there a reason that my first attempt wasn't working properly?

Comment: The other selector was more specific apparently.